# Error=Extra trailing closure passed in call,

Tags: swift, xcode

```
    //creates the session
    let session = AVCaptureSession()

    //Defines the capture device
   AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
   {
      let input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
      session.addInput(input)
    }
```

Not sure how to solve this error any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVCaptureDevice.default` has a return value. You have to assign it to a variable.

And since the value is optional unwrap it safely

```
guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video),
      let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }
session.addInput(input)
```

Comment: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled. Got this when used that code. Also thank you for your help

Comment: sorry I don't understand?

Comment: this is the line where the error comes up let input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)let input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

Comment: I edited the answer and added a `try?` statement. Please reload the page.